# Using ionic plugin Flashlight call crash java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sony

When in ionic i using plugin Flashlight when call method `@TargetApi(23)
  private void setTorchMode(CameraManager cameraManager, String id, boolean switchOn) throws CameraAccessException {
    // since folks may not use SDK 23 to compile we'll use reflection as a temporary solution
    try {
      final Method setTorchMode = cameraManager.getClass().getMethod("setTorchMode", String.class, boolean.class);
      setTorchMode.invoke(cameraManager, id, switchOn);
      callbackContext.success();
    }  catch (Throwable t) {
      callbackContext.error(t.getMessage());
    }
  }`

i get

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: uk.co.sparkenergy.androidapp2, PID: 31200
                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$1@6e1ab65
                                                                                   at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:793)
                                                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1200)
                                                                                   at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$3.run(CameraManager.java:1266)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)`
only 1 device Sony e5633, help please)

Answer (score 0):

all what need, use a deprecated method

```
Camera cam = Camera.open();
if(switchOn){
  Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
  p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
  cam.setParameters(p);
  cam.startPreview();
} else {
  cam.stopPreview();
  cam.release();
}
```

instead

```
  try {
  final Method setTorchMode = cameraManager.getClass().getMethod("setTorchMode", String.class, boolean.class);
  setTorchMode.invoke(cameraManager, id, switchOn);
  callbackContext.success();
}  catch (Throwable t) {
  callbackContext.error(t.getMessage());
}
```